# Angular with asp.net mvc URL change security permissions is given to user

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, security

Apparently I inherited a severe security issue.

User can login and be at this URL

```
https://ourdomain.com/User/Index
```

but problem is the user can put in

```
https://ourdomain.com/User/Edit/16642     and have ACCESS
```

what is the easy solution to fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a vulnerability that is sometimes called 'forced browsing'.
The short answer to your question is that there is no easy way. You have to implement authorization, and that is painful to retrofit into an existing application.

First, you need authentication (ie. users being able to securely log on). I suppose this is already done more or less, otherwise ~/User/Index would be meaningless. (Btw if there is such a vulnerability in the site, you should probably have a look at authentication too, but if standard stuff like forms auth is used, then that is easier to get right.)

Then you need authorization, possibly on two different levels. For each and every call (ie. controller action in MVC), you need to decide, whether the logged on user is allowed to make the call. In .Net MVC a relatively easy way to implement this is [Membership](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) and the [Authorize attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction).

Then depending on the functionality, you may also need fine-grained authorization. For example if your application stores lists of books assigned to specific users with other users not having access, the application needs to decide whether a ~/ShowList/123 request can be fulfilled, based on the logged on user *and* the specific list with id=123 (it's not enough to say that a logged on user can call ~/ShowList because it depends on which one). This is called resource-based authoriozation in Microsoft terms and is discussed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased). If you don't have such distinction between subjects (users) and objects (book lists) of the same type, you may not need this at all.

If your inherited application is large, any of this is painful to implement, but there really is no very easy shortcut unfortunately. You can do it differently, but anything that is much less work than this will probably be flawed, unless your use-case is very specific.

Also please note that Angular doesn't have much to do with this. All authorization must be implemented on the server side, otherwise it's useless.